# What is the correct behavior on Cassandra read timeout?

Tags: cassandra

Our setup is 6 nodes, 3 per DC, 3 way replication per DC. 
We write with EACH_QUORUM. Try reading with LOCAL_QUORUM.

Occasionally, we get read timeouts with an error:

`com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.ReadTimeoutException: Cassandra time
out during read query at consistency ALL (6 responses were required but only 5 replica responded)`

We found that this error actually does not mean what it says [CASSANDRA-7947](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7947). Instead it means that a read repair was triggered and it failed to complete in time.

When we fail with this exception we actually retry with QURUM read, and that fails later with an identical exception.

What we verified is that the writes and reads are happening on the same DC and not crossDC (if this matters). Also a read follows the write and does not happen in parallel.

Any pointers wrt to how we should handle this?

1. Should we retry a couple of times with LOCAL_QUORUM?
2. Should we increase the time out?
3. Should we jump off a cliff?

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

The table schema is along the lines:

```
CREATE TABLE records (
    firstKey text,
    secondKey text,
    data blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (firstKey, secondKey)
) WITH read_repair_chance = 0.0
   AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
   AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
   AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
   AND caching = { 'keys' : 'ALL', 'rows_per_partition' : 'NONE' }
   AND comment = ''
   AND compaction = { 'class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy', 'max_threshold' : 32, 'min_threshold' : 4 }
   AND compression = { 'chunk_length_in_kb' : 64, 'class' : 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor' }
   AND default_time_to_live = 432000
   AND speculative_retry = '99PERCENTILE'
   AND min_index_interval = 128
   AND max_index_interval = 2048
   AND crc_check_chance = 1.0
   AND cdc = false;
```

Query that times out:

```
select * from records where firstKey=XXXXXXX
```

Comment: Can you maybe add here the query which is failing? It would be easier to rule out some possible issues.

Answer (score 1):

Before you jump off the cliff, what I would do in your case:

1.)  Try to read with LOCAL_QUORUM and in case of failure, retry with LOCAL_QUORUM or even with ONE consistency level. 
QUORUM is stronger than LOCAL_QUORUM, so I do not think that retry with a stronger consistency level would help in this case. You have strong consistency as you write with EACH_QUORUM, so depending on your replication factor - if it is really 3 than your reads should be consistent with ONE, too. https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/dml/dmlConfigConsistency.html

2.)  I would also look into how do you fetch your data, for example fetching huge amount of data at once can result in timeouts, too.

3.)  If there is nothing to improve and you still experiencing timeouts - even with ONE consistency, then I would suggest to check your cassandra driver, as it might have some driver side timeout parameter and as a last resort I would update the range_request_timeout_in_ms and read_request_timeout_in_ms in cassandra.yaml

Comment: I don't think consistency ONE is an option. Unless we change write to ALL. 3 consistency is eventual because write with EACH_QUORUM confirms the data on two machines only in this setup.

Comment: But I think if we extend your idea to consistency TWO, this might work. Because if data is written to 2 out of 3 nodes .. consistency TWO should get us the most recent data. No?

Comment: What is your replication factor? - my understanding was, that you have 3 nodes per DC and RF=3, which case all of your node would have the data. 
Replication factor describes, how many copy do you have (per DC) and consistency level is rather related with the clients - how many DC/node the client communicates when handling the data.

Comment: That s exactly the problem ...client returns when two nodes acknowledge per DC. Immediate following read does not guarantee that the third one is also done and has the data.

Comment: If for you consistency is important as well as latency, R+W > RF usually is a safe choice:
I still do not know what is your replication factor, but if you have 2 DC with 3 nodes each and your replication factor is 3 for each DC and you write with EACH_QUORUM, that means that 4 nodes confirmed that it saved the latest data. If you read after (and not paralel) to your write request, than with TWO your reads are still consistent and with ONE they are eventually consistent. 
Have you checked nodetool tablehistograms for your table?

Comment: replication factor is 3. Seems to me the correct solution starts with figuring out why things are slow. Will keep you posted about any findings.